# Codename One SMS reading possible?

Tags: mobile, codenameone

ive searched on official documentation but had no luck, is there any way to read SMS messages in codename one? Or ill have to go native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/clIK-3bDBQM) discusses implementing this natively.

Notice that reading or intercepting SMS's isn't possible in platforms other than Android and even within Android itself it's a contested feature that underwent some limitations and restrictions.

Comment: Edited the answer with some explanation of why native access is required for this

Comment: Thanks for your answer